# Find upper and lower bound when $a$ is negative

Tags: analysis

Let $\alpha \neq 1$. I showed that $1+\alpha+ \dots+\alpha^n=\frac{1-\alpha^{n+1}}{1-\alpha}$.

I want to show that when $0<|\alpha|<1$, that the set $\{1+\alpha+\dots+\alpha^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is bounded. And I want to find the least upper bound.

When $0<\alpha<1$, we have that $\alpha^{n+1}<1 \Rightarrow \frac{1-\alpha^{n+1}}{1-\alpha}>0$.

Also $\alpha^{n+1}>0 \Rightarrow \frac{1-\alpha^{n+1}}{1-\alpha}<\frac{1}{1-\alpha}$.

In order to show that $\frac{1}{1-\alpha}$ is the least upper bound we suppose that there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that $\frac{1}{1-\alpha}-\epsilon$ is a lower bound and we find a contradiction.

Can we find in the same manner the lower and upper bound of the set when $-1<0<\alpha$ ?

Let $-1<a<0 $. We set $\beta=-\alpha$. Then $0<\beta<1$.

Then we have the following.

$1+\dots+\alpha^n=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{1+\beta^{n+1}}{1+\beta} &, \text{ if n is even} \\ 
\frac{1-\beta^{n+1}}{1+\beta} &, \text{ if n is odd} 
\end{matrix}\right.$

We have that $\beta>0 \Rightarrow \beta^{n+1}>0 \Rightarrow \frac{1+\beta^{n+1}}{1+\beta}>\frac{1}{1+\beta}$.

Also $\beta<1 \Rightarrow \beta^{n+1}<\beta \Rightarrow \frac{1+\beta^{n+1}}{1+\beta}<1$.

Furthermore, we have that $\frac{1-\beta^{n+1}}{1+\beta}<\frac{1}{1+\beta}$ and $\frac{1-\beta^{n+1}}{1+\beta}>0$.

Do we use these upper and lower bounds in order to find the lower and least upper bound of the set when $-1<\alpha<0$ ?

Comment: If a sequence is convergent , then it is bounded. This is a geometric sequence which converges for $|x| < 1$, so the conclusion follows.

Comment: I see... @IntegrateThis But how do we find the lower and least upper bound when $-1<\alpha<0$ ?

Comment: For $\alpha <0$, the set isn't bounded by $\frac1{1-\alpha}$. For instance, just look at the first element, $1$.

Comment: Does it hold than when $-1<\alpha<0$ then $1+ \alpha+ \dots+ \alpha^n <1$ ? Is this the leat upper bound? @Arthur

Comment: I would think so, since after that, you can use $\alpha^{2k-1} + \alpha^{2k}<0$ to show that
$$
1 + \alpha + \alpha^2 + \cdots + \alpha^n = 1 + (\alpha + \alpha^2) + (\alpha^3 + \alpha^4) + \cdots + \alpha^n
$$where each bracket is negative, and the last term is either negative, or it's part of a bracket (depending on whether $n$ is even or odd), and either way you get that the above is strictly less than $1$.

Answer (score 1):

It often helps to look at a specific example, where you can do some calculations and pin things down.  In this case, we're looking generally at sets of the form $\{1+\alpha+\alpha^2+\cdots+\alpha^n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ with $-1\lt\alpha\lt1$. So let's pick a couple of nice, easy values of $\alpha$ to look at.

Even though you did the positive $\alpha$ case correctly, it won't hurt to look at $\alpha={1\over2}$, for which the set is

$$\left\{1+{1\over2}+\left(1\over2\right)^2+\cdots+\left(1\over2\right)^n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}=\left\{1,{3\over2},{7\over4},{15\over8},{31\over16},\ldots \right\}$$

It's easy to see here that the lower bound is simply $1$, and the least upper bound is $2$, which, of course, is equal to $1\over1-\alpha$ with $\alpha={1\over2}$.

Now look at $\alpha=-{1\over2}$.  The corresponding set now is

$$\left\{1,{1\over2},{3\over4},{5\over8},{11\over16},\ldots \right\}$$

For *this* set, the least upper bound is $1$ and the greatest lower bound is ${1\over2}$.  That's because after the first two entries in the list, each new entry is *between* the previous two. A bit of thought should convince you that that holds whenever you are alternately adding and subtracting numbers that are getting smaller and smaller, which is the case with $\alpha^n$ when $-1\lt\alpha\lt0$. So in general, if $-1\lt\alpha\lt0$, the upper and lower bounds are simply $1$ and $1+\alpha$.